# How do I change the data I'm getting from an API dynamically based on what button I'm clicking?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm creating a crypto app and I want to dynamically change all the data according to what currency I click on inside of a dropdown menu.

This is the function I use to fetch all the data for the market chart

```
getMarketData = async (currency) => {
try {
  const { data } = await axios.get(
    `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/market_chart?vs_currency=${currency}&days=30&interval=daily`
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need two states - one to hold the selected currency, and one to hold the data returned from the API.
2. Add a handler to the `select` element to listen for change events. Use the value from the selected option as the variable you use for the currency in your URI.
3. When your data is returned update the `data` state
4. Only if you have data display it.

This example uses a mock API to return some data.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

// Mock data
const data = { cz: [1, 3, 5], en: [10, 12, 20], de: [45, 32, 34] };

// Mock API that returns data after a second
function mockApi(currency) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
   setTimeout(() => res(data[currency]), 1000);
  });
}

function Example() {

  // Two states initialised with an empty array
  // for the data, and an empty string for the currency
  const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);
  const [ currency, setCurrency ] = useState('');

  // On the initial render update
  // currency state
  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrency('de');
  }, []);

  // When the currency state is updated
  // call the API
  useEffect(() => {
    if (currency) {
      mockApi(currency).then(data => setData(data));
    }
  }, [currency]);

  // When a new currency is selected
  // update the currency state with the value
  // from the option
  function handleChange(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setCurrency(value);
  }

  // Show the select element and add a change 
  // handler to it. If there's data create a list,
  // otherwise show a loading/error message
  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={handleChange}>
        <option disabled>Choose currency</option>
        <option value="en" selected={currency === "eu"}>EN</option>
        <option value="de" selected={currency === "de"}>DE</option>
        <option value="cz" selected={currency === "cz"}>CZ</option>
      </select>
      {data.length ? (
        <ul>{data.map(el => <li>{el}</li>)}</ul>
      ) : <div>No data</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I noticed that when I use the selected that it updates the state but when the component first renders the state is empty and my data doesn't load

Comment: What data? The whole point of your API is it delivers data based on the currency, and there is no currency selected.

Comment: I want to have a currency selected by default and THEN be able to change it according to selection

Comment: I've updated my answer. Basically 1) use another effect to update the currency state on the initial render, and add `selected` conditions to the options.